# ./phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0 in AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, phantomjs

I am having phantomjs 2.0.0 for screen capturescenario in my Rails application. It is working fine in production mode but when I  moved the code to  AWS, it is showing error as:
(For example I am trying to check the version)

> [root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxxbin]#  ./phantomjs --version 
>   ./phantomjs: error
>   while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: apt-get is not used in this machine, only yum

Comment: So I suppose you are using... centos?

Comment: In this case... I don't exactly know how to continue, but you can try to install openssl like here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105969/installing-openssl-shared-libraries-on-centos-6-5

Comment: Installing openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-8.el7 did not help on CentOS 7.4.1708.